# twitter.com (ssl) not loading

Tags: 14.04, networking, ssl, https, twitter

If I'm trying to go on https://twitter.com it just timeout on Firefox.

If I use curl :

```
vayan@vayan-desktop:~$ curl -v https://twitter.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://twitter.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 199.16.156.70...
* Connected to twitter.com (199.16.156.70) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to twitter.com:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to twitter.com:443
```

or timeout.

Any idea what could do that ? It's only doing that on twitter nowhere else..

Comment: That is not an IP I get for `twitter.com` from Google's DNS servers or this website: http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3atwitter.com&run=toolpage

Comment: Works from here with same IP address. Are you aware of any middleboxes like firewalls in between you and the rest of the internet?

Comment: CA:files are a requirement for ssl connections. To add to the IP that is listed. It has returned to me through a google search as associated to twitter. Google is probably being used as a cloud network

Comment: @Miphix: According to the debug output it successfully finishes the SSL handshake which includes validation of certificate against trusted CA and only after the handshake it gets problems. So it should not be a problem of missing trusted CA. And it has CA in `CApath: /etc/ssl/certs`

Comment: Yeah, I ran the script myself to see if I could duplicate it. I was going to delete my post.